# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, elmah.mvc

> error ASPRUNTIME : The pre-application start initialization method Initialize on type Elmah.Mvc.Bootstrap threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

After updating the NuGet package "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" from `5.2.3` to `5.2.7` , I am getting the above error during publish (My local as well as on the build server)

Upon searching I was able to find this online:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/228901/the-pre-application-start-initialization-method-in.html

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file probably didn't get updated. The DLL version for 5.2.7 is 5.2.7.0. The error message mentions 4.0.0.0. So look for 4.0.0.0 in your web.config and change it to 5.2.7.0.

There will likely be several places in the web.config file to update.

Also, be sure to check the web.config in the Views folder not just the one in the project folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did check all the web.config at the project level as well as in the web.config in the Views folder everything is updated to have 5.2.7.0. Did you check the post here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/228901/the-pre-application-start-initialization-method-in.html

Comment: This is something to do with Elmah, looks like some of its dependencies require 4.0.0.0 of MVC, which I am not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: Oh. You can add a binding redirect to force Elmah to use the version your program is referencing. If Elmah doesn't work with the newer version there's way to reference two versions of a DLL. In either case, I've never tried to do either so I'm not able to offer any more guidance then this.